# Is there a way to use Selenium Webdriver casting it as an Android driver??? I am getting "RemoteWebDriver cannot be cast to AppiumDriver" error

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium-android

The below code

```
Set<String> contextNames1 = ((AppiumDriver<?>)driver).getContextHandles();
```

throws the error cannot be casted. PLease help me in solving this

I am using java-client.7.2

```
driver = new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(new URL(url), capabilities);
driver launch code^
```

I am able to perform click. But not getContextHandles!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Set<String> contextNames1 = ((AndroidDriver<WebElement>)driver).getContextHandles();
```